# The credentials supplied to package were not recognized : AWS IoT and WebAPI app hosted on IIS

Tags: c#, iis, mqtt, aws-iot

The certificates and policies of AWS IoT core are correct as per the AWS documentation and everything works fine in Console app on EC2 instance.
When the same code is deployed on IIS(Web api) then it throws an exception stating "The credentials supplied to package were not recognized"

```
      var CaCert = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(Path.Combine(basefolderPath,"IoTCertificates", "AmazonRootCA1.crt"));
      var ClientCert = new X509Certificate2(Path.Combine(basefolderPath, "IoTCertificates", "xxx.pfx"), "xxxxx");

        string ClientId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        var IotClient = new MqttClient(iotendpoint, 8883, true, CaCert, ClientCert, MqttSslProtocols.TLSv1_2);


        IotClient.MqttMsgPublishReceived += Client_MqttMsgPublishReceived;
        IotClient.MqttMsgSubscribed += Client_MqttMsgSubscribed;
        IotClient.Connect(ClientId);

        Console.WriteLine("Connected");
```

The error logs are as below :

{"ClassName":"uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.Exceptions.MqttConnectionException","Message":"Exception connecting to the broker","Data":null,"InnerException":{"NativeErrorCode":-2146893043,"ClassName":"System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception","Message":"The credentials supplied to the package were not recognized","Data":null,"InnerException":null,"HelpURL":null,"StackTraceString":"   at System.Net.SSPIWrapper.AcquireCredentialsHandle(SSPIInterface SecModule, String package, CredentialUse intent, SecureCredential scc)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.AcquireCredentialsHandle(CredentialUse credUsage, SecureCredential& secureCredential)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.AcquireClientCredentials(Byte[]& thumbPrint)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.GenerateToken(Byte[] input, Int32 offset, Int32 count, Byte[]& output)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SecureChannel.NextMessage(Byte[] incoming, Int32 offset, Int32 count)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartSendBlob(Byte[] incoming, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessReceivedBlob(Byte[] buffer, Int32 count, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslState.StartReceiveBlob(Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslState.CheckCompletionBeforeNextReceive(ProtocolToken message, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ForceAuthentication(Boolean receiveFirst, Byte[] buffer, AsyncProtocolRequest asyncRequest)\r\n   at System.Net.Security.SslState.ProcessAuthentication(LazyAsyncResult lazyResult)\r\n   at uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.MqttNetworkChannel.Connect() in c:\Users\ppatierno\Source\Repos\m2mqtt\M2Mqtt\Net\MqttNetworkChannel.cs:line 266\r\n   at uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.MqttClient.Connect(String clientId, String username, String password, Boolean willRetain, Byte willQosLevel, Boolean willFlag, String willTopic, String willMessage, Boolean cleanSession, UInt16 keepAlivePeriod) in c:\Users\ppatierno\Source\Repos\m2mqtt\M2Mqtt\MqttClient.cs:line 556","RemoteStackTraceString":null,"RemoteStackIndex":0,"ExceptionMethod":"8\nAcquireCredentialsHandle\nSystem, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089\nSystem.Net.SSPIWrapper\nSystem.Net.SafeFreeCredentials AcquireCredentialsHandle(System.Net.SSPIInterface, System.String, System.Net.CredentialUse, System.Net.SecureCredential)","HResult":-2147467259,"Source":"System","WatsonBuckets":null},"HelpURL":null,"StackTraceString":"   at uPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.MqttClient.Connect(String clientId, String username, String password, Boolean willRetain, Byte willQosLevel, Boolean willFlag, String willTopic, String willMessage, Boolean cleanSession, UInt16 keepAlivePeriod) in c:\Users\ppatierno\Source\Repos\m2mqtt\M2Mqtt\MqttClient.cs:line 560\r\n  ","RemoteStackTraceString":null,"RemoteStackIndex":0,"ExceptionMethod":"8\nConnect\nM2Mqtt.Net, Version=4.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null\nuPLibrary.Networking.M2Mqtt.MqttClient\nByte Connect(System.String, System.String, System.String, Boolean, Byte, Boolean, System.String, System.String, Boolean, UInt16)","HResult":-2146233088,"Source":"M2Mqtt.Net","WatsonBuckets":null}

Comment: Does your web api could run the codes with the certificate in the web api?  It seems there are something wrong with the certificate.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually everything runs locally but when deployed on IIS it throws this exception. The certificates used are same in both the cases. Are there any permission issues with IIS?

Comment: I suggest you could try to check the certificate folder to make sure your application pool identity has the perission to access the folder. Details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/manage/configuring-security/application-pool-identities#securing-resources).

Comment: I tried that . It is working locally on IIS when deployed but on the AWS Instance it does not work and throws the same error. Tried setting the above permissions but no success.